# Undefined control sequence "\end{frame}"

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex

I am totally new to Latex, I am seeing error at end of line **\end{frame}** , not able to figure it out why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% --------------------------------------------------- %
%                  Presentation info                  %
% --------------------------------------------------- %
\title{Test1}
\author{AMITH KOTIAN}
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}{HAND REHABILITATION SYSTEM}
    \chaptype{ \LARGE \textbf {1.Design Consideration}}
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{3mm}
            \begin{Large}
            \item User safety must be guaranteed.
            \item It can be easily worn.
           \end{Large}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] and not juts code fragments.

Comment: In particular, please tell us how you defined `\chaptype`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz defined? are you asking about include package. sorry i am totally new to this

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable document, that allows us to reproduce your problem. It should include a documentclass as well all necessary packages

Comment: And please post it as one code block, so we don;t have to puzzle together all the pieces

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz understood, i have made it short and posted full code. i tried one experiment removing by \chaptype error will go. i need that in chapter wise what package i need to make use of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\chaptype` is not defined. I have no idea what you might want it to do, but you must either load a package with defines it or define it yourself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% --------------------------------------------------- %
%                  Presentation info                  %
% --------------------------------------------------- %
\title{Test1}
\author{AMITH KOTIAN}
\date{January 2021}

\newcommand{\chaptype}[1]{{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}{HAND REHABILITATION SYSTEM}
    \chaptype{ \LARGE \textbf {1.Design Consideration}}
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{3mm}
            \begin{Large}
            \item User safety must be guaranteed.
            \item It can be easily worn.
           \end{Large}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```